# Setting a Table Component in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I've created a table, populated from a database.

The table is returned from a separate method as type Table.

Upon receiving the table, I do the following:

```
Table tbl = fC.makeTable();
findTblContainer(f).addComponent(tbl);
```

When running the application, I only get a small white box with no apparent text inside. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks.
~Ari

EDIT:

This is the method:

```
protected void beforeFines(Form f) {
        try {
            Table tbl = fC.makeTable();
            findTblContainer(f).addComponent(tbl);
            findTblContainer(f).animateLayout(5);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("No fines found!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the layout of the table container? I suggest placing the table in a center of a `BorderLayout` although that isn't essential.

If this is done after the form was shown you need to `revalidate()` the form or use `animateLayout(int)/animateHierarchy(int)` or some other method to indicate the layout change completed.

Comment: I had it as a basic FlowLayout but I changed it now to BorderLayout. Now it's bringing up an error with the layout constraints. Sorry I'm new to this Shai! :P --- And thanks so much! I edited my first post with the whole method.

Comment: No problem just change the code to addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, table)

Comment: Ok just tried that. I don't get an error but the table is still coming up as an empty white block. Could I be doing something wrong with the interface? I'm fairly sure the table itself is correct.

Comment: Did you revalidate/animateLayout after adding the table?

Comment: Yep. Still nothing. Is it wrong to use the before action maybe?

Comment: animate layout is redundant in the before form, you should remove it (just takes up CPU). If this still doesn't work I'd like to see the code of the table creation.

Comment: Hi Shai! I ended up finding the problem. It was an error with the theme I was using. The wooden one. It seems to have a glitch with the tables. I changed theme and it all worked...